# Screen output of remote Unix host

Tags: unix, testing, sahi

I want to run my test suite on remote Unix host. Test suite is suppose to open firefox and perform automated tests. It's jbehave test suite and uses Sahi test automation tool. Currently I run suite on my local machine. I want to run the same suite on a remote host and want to see opened firefox browser on my local machine's screen.

Comment: The simplest way to see the remote system is to enable vnc on the X server. This is much more of a superuser question rather than a programming question, though.

Answer (score 0):

To run such tests I use [Xvnc](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/xvnc.html). It's an X server that is accessible through VNC protocol.

If you use continuous integration tools like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), check if they can start it for you.